# Merge two object arrays for Chart

Tags: javascript, arrays, backbone.js, lodash

I've two arrays which I'm going to merge and then load in chart.

**range** = date array generated from moment.js, there is date of every day in example one month or specific date range with one another attribute count: "0"

[image]

**data** = fetched data from database through backbone

[image]

Now I want set atrribute count from data count, where date is same in both arrays.
I'm using lodash...

```
_.forEach(range, function(n) {

    console.log(n.date.substring(0, date.length-6));
    // IF n.date = date from data replace count to value from data array


});
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: What issue do you have?

Comment: I don't know how to find it in another array...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [_.find](https://lodash.com/docs#find) to match your items in the range to the ones in the data.

```
_.forEach(range, function(r) {
    var d = _.find(data, {date: r.date}); //Find an item in "data" with date matching r.date
    if(d) {
         r.count = d.count;
    }
});
```